# Most efficient way to multiply a data frame by a vector

Tags: r

What would be the most efficient way to multiply each column of a data frame by a vector?

e.g. data frame (`df`) has the following columns (`col1, col2, col3, col4`) and vector (`v`) has the following elements (`v1,v2,v3`).

I want the output to be: `col2*v1, col3*v2, col4*v3`

I've been trying `df[c(2:4)] * c(v1,v2,v3)` but it seems like the elements of the vector are not multiplying every single row of each column.

Comment: You can't find out anything about efficiency without looking at how long the overall operation takes and the resources that are required. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/rbenchmark/ for some benchmarking tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try (using `df` and `v` from Richard Scriven's answer):

```
df[-1] <- t(t(df[-1]) * v)
df
#   a  x  y   z
# 1 a  5 40 105
# 2 b 10 50 120
# 3 c 15 60 135
```

When you multiply a matrix by a vector, it multiplies columnwise. Since you want to multiply your rows by the vector, we transpose `df[-1]` using `t`, multiply by `v`, and transpose back using `t`.

It seems like this approach has a slight edge in benchmarking over the `Map` approach, and a significant advantage over `sweep`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
rscriven <- function(df, v) cbind(df[1], Map(`*`, df[-1], v))
josilber <- function(df, v) cbind(df[1], t(t(df[-1]) * v))
dardisco <- function(df, v) cbind(df[1], sweep(df[-1], MARGIN=2, STATS=v, FUN="*"))
df2 <- cbind(data.frame(rep("a", 1000)), matrix(rnorm(100000), nrow=1000))
v2 <- rnorm(100)
all.equal(rscriven(df2, v2), josilber(df2, v2))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(rscriven(df2, v2), dardisco(df2, v2))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(rscriven(df2, v2), josilber(df2, v2), dardisco(df2, v2))
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr       min        lq    median        uq        max neval
#  rscriven(df2, v2)  5.276458  5.378436  5.451041  5.587644   9.470207   100
#  josilber(df2, v2)  2.545144  2.753363  3.099589  3.704077   8.955193   100
#  dardisco(df2, v2) 11.647147 12.761184 14.196678 16.581004 132.428972   100
```

Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out that the `Map` approach is a good deal faster for 100x larger data frames:

```
df2 <- cbind(data.frame(rep("a", 10000)), matrix(rnorm(10000000), nrow=10000))
v2 <- rnorm(1000)
microbenchmark(rscriven(df2, v2), josilber(df2, v2), dardisco(df2, v2))
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr       min         lq     median        uq       max neval
#  rscriven(df2, v2)  75.74051   90.20161   97.08931  115.7789  259.0855   100
#  josilber(df2, v2) 340.72774  388.17046  498.26836  514.5923  623.4020   100
#  dardisco(df2, v2) 928.81128 1041.34497 1156.39293 1271.4758 1506.0348   100
```

It seems like you'll need to benchmark to determine which approach is fastest for your application.

Comment: +1 for being a good Samirtan!! Thanks for sharing the benchmarking results!

Comment: This result is quite sensitive to how big `df2` is. Try upping it to 1000 columns and 10000 rows and the results will reverse.

Comment: @thelatemail ty -- I've added these benchmarking results as well.

Comment: @josilber - at the end of the day, it's a matter of fractions of seconds. Unless you're running this hundreds of times in a piece of code, you'll blink and miss it.

Comment: Another option would be `df[-1] <- lapply(seq_along(v), function(x) df[x+1] * v[x])` (which seems to be only slightly slower than @josilber's answer for the df2 sample data)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Map` for this.  Here's an example

```
> ( df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:3], x = 1:3, y = 4:6, z = 7:9) )
#   a x y z
# 1 a 1 4 7
# 2 b 2 5 8
# 3 c 3 6 9    
> v <- c(5, 10, 15)
> cbind(df[1], Map(`*`, df[-1], v))
#   a  x  y   z
# 1 a  5 40 105
# 2 b 10 50 120
# 3 c 15 60 135
```

In this example,

- column `x` is multiplied by `v[1]` (5)
- column `y` is multiplied by `v[2]` (10)
- column `z` is multiplied by `v[3]` (15)
- `cbind` is used to attach the unused column `a` to the columns we operated on

Answer (score 2):

Not as fast, but more flexible:

```
sweep(df[-1], MARGIN=2, STATS=v, FUN="*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple 'apply' function can also be used here, reading by rows:

```
df[-1]= (t(apply(df[-1],1, FUN=function(x)x*v)))
df
  a  x  y   z
1 a  5 40 105
2 b 10 50 120
3 c 15 60 135
```

Comment: Alternately, you could use `t(apply(df[-1], 1, "*", v))` here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. '*' can be used as a function.